# My Cache simulator isnt running properly, can someone help me why that is?

Tags: c, caching

For my studies, I need to make a cache simulator in C. I don't need to actually save the data but just count the misses, hits and evictions. The input is s, E, b for sets lines and block offset and I get a trace folder which is structured like this:

identifier address, size

where the identifier is split into "S" for a store, "L" for a load and "M" for a load and store.

This is a given example:

```
L 10,1 miss
M 20,1 miss hit
L 22,1 hit
S 18,1 hit
L 110,1 miss eviction
L 210,1 miss eviction
M 12,1 miss eviction hit
hits:4 misses:5 evictions:3
```

I always get the wrong results.  Most of the time, I have way too few hits. Did I do something wrong in my calculations?

```
#include "cache lab.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <getopt.h>

// Cache line structure
typedef struct {
    int valid;   // Valid bit
    int tag;     // Tag field
    int lru;     // LRU counter
    // Additional fields for data, depending on the cache structure
} CacheLine;

// Cache structure
typedef struct {
    int sets;        // Number of sets
    int lines;       // Number of lines per set
    int block_size;  // Block size (in bytes)
    CacheLine *cache; // Cache array
} Cache;

// Initialize the cache
void initCache(Cache *cache) {
    // Allocate memory for the cache array
    cache->cache = (CacheLine *)malloc(cache->sets * cache->lines * sizeof(CacheLine));

    // Initialize cache lines
    for (int i = 0; i < cache->sets * cache->lines; i++) {
        cache->cache[i].valid = 0;
        cache->cache[i].tag = 0;
        cache->cache[i].lru = 0;
    }
}

// Simulate a cache access
void accessCache(Cache *cache, char operation, unsigned address, int size, int *hits, int *misses, int *evicts) {
    int set_index = (address / cache->block_size) % cache->sets;
    int tag = address / (cache->block_size * cache->sets);

    // Check for a cache hit
    for (int i = 0; i < cache->lines; i++) {
        int index = set_index * cache->lines + i;

        if (cache->cache[index].valid && cache->cache[index].tag == tag) {
            // Cache hit
            (*hits)++;
            cache->cache[index].lru = 0;  // Reset LRU counter

            // For modify (M) operations, we count it as a hit and a miss
            if (operation == 'M') {
                (*misses)++;
            }

            return;
        }
    }

    // Cache miss
    (*misses)++;

    // Find an empty line or evict the least recently used line
    int lru_index = set_index * cache->lines;
    for (int i = 1; i < cache->lines; i++) {
        int index = set_index * cache->lines + i;
        if (!cache->cache[index].valid) {
            lru_index = index;
            break;
        } else if (cache->cache[index].lru > cache->cache[lru_index].lru) {
            lru_index = index;
        }
    }

    // Check if eviction is needed
    if (cache->cache[lru_index].valid) {
        (*evicts)++;
    }

    // Update the cache line
    cache->cache[lru_index].valid = 1;
    cache->cache[lru_index].tag = tag;
    cache->cache[lru_index].lru = 0;  // Reset LRU counter

    // Update LRU counters
    for (int i = 0; i < cache->lines; i++) {
        int index = set_index * cache->lines + i;
        if (index != lru_index) {
            cache->cache[index].lru++;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int opt;
    int s = 0, b = 0, E = 0;
    char *t;

    // Parse command-line options
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "s:b:E:t:")) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
            case 's':
                s = atoi(optarg);
                break;
            case 'b':
                b = atoi(optarg);
                break;
            case 'E':
                E = atoi(optarg);
                break;
            case 't':
                t = optarg;
                

                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s -s <s> -b <b> -E <E> -t <t>\n", argv[0]);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    FILE *pfile = fopen(t, "r");
    char operation;
    unsigned address;
    int size;

    // Check if required options are provided
    if (s == 0 || b == 0 || E == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Missing required options. Usage: %s -s <s> -b <b> -E <E>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Calculate the number of lines in each set (cache associativity)
    int lines_per_set = 1 << E;

    // Cache configuration
    Cache cache;
    cache.sets = 1 << s;
    cache.lines = lines_per_set;
    cache.block_size = 1 << b;

    // Cache statistics
    int hits = 0;
    int misses = 0;
    int evicts = 0;

    // Initialize the cache
    initCache(&cache);

    // Simulate cache accesses based on the trace file
    while (fscanf(pfile, " %c %x, %d", &operation, &address, &size) > 0) {
        accessCache(&cache, operation, address, size, &hits, &misses, &evicts);
    }
    fclose(pfile);

    // Output cache statistics
    printSummary(hits, misses, evicts);

    // Free allocated memory
    free(cache.cache);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not appear to be C++ code.

Comment: On the face of it, your `fscanf()` line ignores the 'miss', 'hit' and 'eviction' words that appear after the operation, address and size inputs.  The `accessCache()` function has no access to `pfile` because that's local to `main()` and not passed to the function, so it can't clean up the leftovers.  In fact, you should only be reading the first line of the file.  You can demonstrate this by printing the values from the `fscanf()` each time it is called successfully.  The print should be before calling `accessCache ()` and the output should end with a newline (and be printed to `stderr`?).

Comment: @tadman C++ is a superset of C after all.

Comment: (mostly the same)

Comment: @AlvinCHENG: C and C++ are two very different languages.  What is appropriate in C is usually not appropriate in C++; many things in C++ cannot be done in C using the same notation.  On SO, the two languages are best treated as separate, and only dual-tag with the two language tags if the question is about the interworking of C and C++, or perhaps a contrast between the two languages.  Using the term "C/C++" will earn derision and downvotes.

Comment: True, you probably won't be using `malloc` and `free` in cpp instead of `new`

Comment: @AlvinCHENG Don't even start. They are two different languages, they have different rules. C++ tries to be a superset, but it is not C.